# Network connection of raspberry pi 3 B+ in my pc

Tags: wifi

When I connected my raspberry pi to my PC( windows 7) in the network setting I am not able to find the raspberry connected to my PC.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- There are a lot of possibilities. What happened if you connect RPi to a Switch/Router? Are you sure the cable hasn't damaged? The network adapter isn't disabled on RPi and the PC?

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/107860/edit) your question and paste the output of these commands to it: `ip addr` and `sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.